# Why can't it read the xml data properly?

Tags: python-3.x, xml

Okay first of all, in my experience as a beginner in programming I never had encounter this kind of weirdness in my whole life.

Hello I have a very large xml file and I cannot show it here but I can show the first part here as an image

[image: First data in XML]

As you can see the arrows are pointing is the very first  tag along with its respective children. Now I have here a program that reads that **LARGE** xml file and as you can see there is only the first 5 of it, here is the code

```
def parse(word,translator,file):
    language_target = "de"
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        data = [] #[(a,b,c),(a,b,c),(a,b,c)]


        file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),file)
        nsmap = {"xml": "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}
        for event, elem in ET.iterparse(file_path,events=("start","end")):

            if event == "start" and elem.tag == "tu":
                temp_list = []
                sentence = elem.find(f'.//tuv[@xml:lang="{language_target}"]', nsmap).find('seg', nsmap).text

    else:
        print("\nNo such File")


    os.system("pause")
```

There's no need to give attention much on the parameters, those three just gets a word and a translator and a filename. Now on this part is where I read the **LARGE** xml file

```
nsmap = {"xml": "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}
        for event, elem in ET.iterparse(file_path,events=("start","end")):

            if event == "start" and elem.tag == "tu":
                temp_list = []
                sentence = elem.find(f'.//tuv[@xml:lang="{language_target}"]', nsmap).find('seg', nsmap).text
```

What happens there is it gets all of the  tags cause I want to get the text of its children. Now look what happens here when I run the program

[image: Error without print]

It says that it is a `NoneType` object, now I am wondering how can it be a `NoneType` object where there `YOU CAN SEE` it is definitely `NOT a NoneType Object` cause it has the corresponding data and this is the first data and how can it said that it is **NoneType**?

```
<tu>
  <tuv xml:lang="de"><seg>- Gloucester? ! - Die sollten doch in Serfam sein.</seg></tuv>
  <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>They should have surrendered when they had the chance!</seg></tuv>
</tu>
```

Now look what happens when I put `print()` right below this code `sentence = elem.find(f'.//tuv[@xml:lang="{language_target}"]', nsmap).find('seg', nsmap).text`

So it would be like this:

```
sentence = elem.find(f'.//tuv[@xml:lang="{language_target}"]', nsmap).find('seg', nsmap).text
print(sentence)
```

[image: IT WORKS]

As you can see now it works! however it stopped again on a specific data but I checked it and it is not `NoneType` there is **DATA**  on that part and I am wondering why is it saying it to be `NoneType`. Also I am so mindblown by the fact that I just put a `print()` function below the `sentence` code and it made a lot of difference. Can someone help me with this? To be honest I am really mindblown by this and I do not know what is happening, I feel like there is a lack of understanding that I am having in reading the XML file with python. Can someone help me with it and guide me? maybe there's a better way to do this.

Thank you so much! I really need your help stackoverflow community! Thank you!

Also here I made a run again and got this result

```
Jeremiah! Jetzt bist du dran!
Jeremiah, this is a purge!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "us24.py", line 76, in <module>
    parse(word,translator,file)
  File "us24.py", line 35, in parse
    english_translation = elem.find('.//tuv[@xml:lang="en"]', nsmap).find('seg', nsmap).text #Human Translation
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

and it again said **NoneType** where in fact I looked at my xml file and there is **DATA** on it!

```
<tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="de"><seg>Jeremiah! Jetzt bist du dran!</seg></tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>Jeremiah, this is a purge!</seg></tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="de"><seg>Suzaku!</seg></tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>Suzaku-kun!</seg></tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="de"><seg>- CÃ©cile-san? !</seg></tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>Cecil-san!</seg></tuv>
    </tu>
    <tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="de"><seg>- Hier ist's zu gefahrlich!</seg></tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>It's dangerous here!</seg></tuv>
    </tu>
```

The next one it should be reading is this , but it says **NoneType** how can it be Nonetype where you can see it has the correct data and why are the others working besides this one? :(

```
<tu>
      <tuv xml:lang="de"><seg>Suzaku!</seg></tuv>
      <tuv xml:lang="en"><seg>Suzaku-kun!</seg></tuv>
    </tu>
```

Comment: Try not to post screenshots of text. Post the text. It makes things easier for everybody.

Comment: *"I am wondering why is it saying it to be `NoneType`"* -- Well, you call `elem.find('...').find('...')`. If the first `.find()` finds nothing, it returns `None`, which will lead to this error at the second `.find()`.

Comment: @Tomalak   Yes I get that but as you can see there , there is the corresponding data and the other ones work tho... so I just find it weird that why isn't it working on another one. I think there could be something happening that isn't based of what I understand. Is the code of reading the xml file fine right?

Comment: @Tomalak noted with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simplify your parsing approach.

Take advantage of the event-based parser and remove all `.find()` calls. Look at it this way: The parser presents to you all the elements in the XML, you only have to decide which ones you find interesting.

In this case, the interesting elements have a certain tag name ('seg') and they need to be in a section with the right language. It's easy to have a Boolean flag (say, `is_correct_language`) that is toggled based on the `xml:lang` attribute of the previous `<tuv>` element.

Since the `start` event is enough for checking attributes and text, we don't need the parser to notify us of `end` events at all:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def parse(word, translator, file, language_target='de'):
    is_correct_language = False

    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(file, events=('start',)):
        if elem.tag == 'tuv':
            xml_lang = elem.attrib.get('{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang', '')
            is_correct_language = xml_lang.startswith(language_target)
        elif is_correct_language and elem.tag == 'seg':
            yield elem.text
```

usage:

```
for segment in parse('', '', 'test.xml', 'de'):
    print(segment)
```

Other notes:

- I've used a generator function (`yield` instead of `return`) as those tend to be more versatile.
- I don't think that using `os.getcwd()` is a good idea in the function, as this needlessly restricts the function's usefulness.
  By default Python will look in the current working directory anyway,
  so in the best case prefixing the filename with `os.getcwd()` is
  superfluous. In the worst case you want to parse a file from a
  different directory and your function would needlessly break the
  path.
- "File exists" checks are useless. Just open the file (or call `ET.iterparse()` on it, same thing). Wrap the whole thing in `try`/`except` and catch the `FileNotFoundError`, if you want to handle this situation.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll look onto it :)

Comment: @Jan Also take a look at the notes I added.

Comment: I feel like I am getting your point... thank you! let me try first this and study on it THANK YOU!

Comment: Okay noted Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ohhh my goodness!!! I am getting the point of your provided program and I think it is more efficient! Let me apply it first and study more on it then I'll be back :D Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello Thank you so much for the help! I understand the concept of you have made with the code, It gave me a lot of realization on how to solve my problem... Thank you so much! I'll check this answer :)

Comment: The reason I went into a lot if `.find()` is I got into a lot of web scraping with `BeautifulSoup` so I just got the mind of the concept how you would get data or parse using `bs4` :D

Comment: and parsing xml data is quite different after all

Comment: @Jan ...at least with an event-based parser. With a DOM parser it's not a lot different from what you already know. The event-based approach is especially well-suited for very large XML files (e.g. gigabytes) and it's fastest when you don't mix it with the DOM-based approach (such as finding elements with XPath). Of course `ElementTree` lets you mix the approaches - use whatever feels natural or runs well enough. "Pure" event-based parsing it not always feasible.